CSS selector for element with exact text match
With :contains("Test") I can select elements that include Test, but this also matches Test 123 for example. How can I only select elements where its text is exactly Test?
:contains("^Test$") did not work unfortunately...

CSS alone doesn't provide a way to select elements based on exact text content. U can achieve this only using some extra JavaScript.

@DA What would be that extra JS?

@0stone0 The question is different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text in that regard, that there is only a partial match needed/required, instead of an exact match

document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(element => {if (element.textContent.trim() === 'Test') {...}}); like this....
